# Get the number of occurance and string from List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string>` where some of the values are repeating. I want to get the particular `string` and it's number of occurrence. I tried couple of scenarios where it works and in one particular it doesn't and want to understand why?

Code:

```
var list  = new List<string>() { "Yahoo" , "MSN", "Yahoo", "MSN", "Yahoo", "MSN", "MSN" };

//Works:
var lineWithNumberOfOccurance = linesFromTextFile.GroupBy(word => word).Select(g => new {Count = g.Count(), g.Key});

//Doesn't work:
var lineWithNumberOfOccurance = linesFromTextFile.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Count(), x => x.Key);
```

Error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

However, Following works fine.

```
var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};
var test = list.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Count(), x => x.Key);
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

You mixed `Key` and `Value` of your dictionary. You are trying to use `Count` as *key*.

So if two different words occur the same number of times, you have the same key for two words. Just change the line to

```
var lineWithNumberOfOccurance = linesFromTextFile.GroupBy(x => x)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

---

Your last example works because `1` occurs one time, `2` occurs two times and `3` occurs three times, so there is no key collision. Your first example should therefor work, too, but I guess you just didn't show the correct test values in your question.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They key in a dictionary must be unique.  You're using the *count* as the key, so if you have 2 words that both appear the same number of times then you'll get an exception.

You should use the *word* as the key given you already know that's unique.

```
linesFromTextFile.GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```